# sharedPreferences not saving the data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store the steps count of a user but when I restart or power-off my mobile the data goes away. SharedPreferences is not saving the data. It goes to 0 when I enter into the app after restarting my mobile. How to solve it?

The code is given below:

```
package com.threemusketeers.healthmaster;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Pedometer extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private TextView textView;

private SensorManager mSensorManager;

private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;

private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedometer);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)
            getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;

    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = (int) values[0];
    }
    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        editor.putInt("steps", value).commit();
        textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + sharedPreferences.getInt("steps", 0));
    } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
        // For test only. Only allowed value is 1.0 i.e. for step taken
        editor.putInt("steps", value).commit();
        textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + sharedPreferences.getInt("steps", 0));
    }
}

   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

   }

   protected void onResume() {

       super.onResume();

       mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor,

            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
       mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor,

            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

   }

   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
       mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);
   }
}
```

Comment: you also need to call `editor.commit();`

Comment: i called it already..

editor.putInt("steps", value).commit();

Comment: ah, sorry...missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You do something that is odd in itself, namely write the value to `SharedPreferences` and then get it from there again which is an unnecesarry IO operation.

This also causes your problem since the step counter counts

> number of steps taken by the user *since the last reboot*

(From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-stepcounter))

When you reboot the device, the count is reset to 0. You don't update the TextView in `onCreate`, but rather when the step count changes (from 0 to 1) overwrite the previous value in SharedPreferences and update the value of the TextView from there.

You need to change your saving logic to first read the value from sharedprefs and add that as a base value if the current step count is lower than the saved value. Or just count steps with the step detector yourself.

Comment: Thanx a lot.....can u tell me how can make the step counter counts my steps although my app is not running? The app counts steps only when the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SharedPreferences like below mentioned:

**To save data:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", "Ravish");
editor.commit();
```

**To retrieve data:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String name= prefs.getString("name");
```

Comment: thanks.....but when i reboot my mobile, instead of increment of 1 for each steps, it is incremented by a big value